# FailedPreconditionError: best_delivery_model\variables is not a directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, файловые-пути

При запуске следующего кода:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0.001,
                           patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')

chkpt = ModelCheckpoint('best_delivery_model',
                        monitor='val_loss',
                        verbose=1,
                        save_best_only=True,
                        mode='auto')

callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

hist = n_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 epochs=20,
                 validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                 callbacks=callbacks)
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
Epoch 1/20
229/230 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1759 - accuracy: 0.7653
Epoch 1: val_loss improved from inf to 0.23027, saving model to best_delivery_model
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-5acf5f5dc571> in <module>
     12 callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]
     13 
---> 14 hist = n_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
     15                  batch_size=batch_size,
     16                  epochs=20,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in recursive_create_dir_v2(path)
    511     errors.OpError: If the operation fails.
    512   """
--> 513   _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
    514 
    515 

FailedPreconditionError: best_delivery_model\variables is not a directory
```

best_delivery_model\variables - такая папка есть, но он тут почему-то автоматически ставит обратный слэш

Есть варианты решения?